# UICollectionView calling height for every section in massive collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView, using UICollectionViewFlowLayout for its' layout. It's backed by the resulting array of a core data query, and has 10000 items of sample data in there, to test its performance in such a situation. Each item has its own section, to allow me to attach a header to the top, and some items in a future version will require additional cells in their section, so this is a good setup.

I have the following UICollectionViewFlowDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource functions implemented:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```

And the setup of my collectionview looks like this:

```
let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

self.conversationCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
```

So then I run the app, and upon initially loading the app, *and* upon performing `insertSection` (when I wish to add a single new entry) I noticed a delay of a few seconds. So I logged out the calls to each of the delegate methods.

Upon the app launching, it calls `numberOfItemsInSection`, `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` and `referenceSizeForFooterInSection`, for every of the 10000 sections and items.

Of the items onscreen, it additionally calls `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `viewForSupplementaryItemOfKind`, which I'd expect.

So then I add in:

```
collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
collectionViewLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero
collectionViewLayout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero
```

But this makes no difference to the calls made.

What I want, ideally, is to be able to give an estimated section size, and then only have the section and cell height functions called when they're about to be shown on-screen.

Comment: Where do you add in the lines with the `collectionViewLayout`? If you add them in after the collection view has already finished laying out, it won't refresh the layout. If that's the case, you'll have to do `collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` (or better yet, set those properties in the `init`).

Comment: I do add those to the collection view layout, before initialising the collection view with that layout.

Comment: Hi @Andrew - did you ever get a workaround for this? I am encountering the same issue (showing a UICollectionView with a sectioned data source of several thousand items and having numberOfItemsInSection called once for each section), looking for as much information as I can!